# How to get the file content type from the REST service?

Tags: rest, jersey, dropwizard

I have a REST service to upload a file, is there a way to know what content type I might be getting? The user using my REST service might upload a PDF, Word or Excel document.

```
 @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Path("/details/documents")
    public Response uploadDocument(@FormDataParam("file") File documentContent, 
                                   @FormDataParam("documentName") String documentName) 
                                   throws Exception { 
 //more implementation code here to upload the file.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `File` as a method parameter, you can use `FormDataBodyPart`, and then call `getMediaType()`. If you want to get the part's body as a `File`, just use `getValueAs(File.class)` or if you want the input stream just use `InputStream.class`.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/details/documents")
public Response uploadDocument(@FormDataParam("file") FormDataBodyPart part) { 
    MediaType mediaType = part.getMediaType();
    File file = part.getValueAs(File.class);
}
```